# How to solve that AttachAsync of a DownloadOperation does not return immediately?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

When using the Background Transfer API we must iterate through current data transfers to start them again ahen the App restarts after a termination (i.e. system shutdown). To get progress information and to be able to cancel the data transfers they must be attached using AttachAsync.

My problem is that AttachAsync only returns when the data transfer is finished. That makes sense in some scenarios. But when having multiple data transfers the next transfer in the list would not be started until the currently attached is finished. My solution to this problem was to handle the Task that AttachAsync().AsTask() returns in the classic way (not use await but continuations):

```
IReadOnlyList<DownloadOperation> currentDownloads =
   await BackgroundDownloader.GetCurrentDownloadsAsync();
foreach (var downloadOperation in currentDownloads)
{
   Task task = downloadOperation.AttachAsync().AsTask();

   DownloadOperation operation = downloadOperation;
   task.ContinueWith(_ =>
   {
      // Handle success
      ...
   }, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion,
   TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

   task.ContinueWith(_ =>
   {
      // Handle cancellation
      ...
  }, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled,
  TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

  task.ContinueWith(t =>
  {
     // Handle errors
      ...

  }, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted,
  TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

It kind of works (in the actual code I add the downloads to a ListBox). The loop iterates through all downloads and executes StartAsync. But the downloads are not really started all at the same time. Only one is runninng at a time and only if it finishes the next one continues.

Any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

The whole point of `Task` is to allow you to have the option of parallel operations.  If you `await` then you are telling the code to serialize the operations; if you don't await, then you are telling the code to parallelize.

What you can do is add each download task to a list, telling the code to parallelize.  You can then wait for tasks to finish, one by one.

How about something like:

```
IReadOnlyList<DownloadOperation> currentDownloads = 
    await BackgroundDownloader.GetCurrentDownloadsAsync();
if (currentDownloads.Count > 0)
{
    List<Task<DownloadOperation>> tasks = new List<Task<DownloadOperation>>();
    foreach (DownloadOperation downloadOperation in currentDownloads)
    {
        // Attach progress and completion handlers without waiting for completion
        tasks.Add(downloadOperation.AttachAsync().AsTask());
    }

    while (tasks.Count > 0)
    {
        // wait for ANY download task to finish
        Task<DownloadOperation> task = await Task.WhenAny<DownloadOperation>(tasks);
        tasks.Remove(task);

        // process the completed task...
        if (task.IsCanceled)
        {
            // handle cancel
        }
        else if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            // handle exception
        }
        else if (task.IsCompleted)
        {
            DownloadOperation dl = task.Result;
            // handle completion (e.g. add to your listbox)
        }
        else
        {
            // should never get here....
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the question was not about Tasks. It was about the Problem that AttachAsync does not return until the download is completed. My solution does work. The real answer to my question would be that this behavior of AttachAsync allows us to detect when a download is finished.

Comment: @Jürgen Bayer - Perhaps I am just not understanding where your issue is. When I run my code above in the debugger, the line that does the `AttachAsync` returns immediately. The only place that waits is the `while` loop, which is supposed to wait - it handles the completion event of the downloads.

Comment: That AttachAsync returns immediately is by purpose since I don't call it with await but use the returned task to create continuations. The issue was: If an App was terminated while multiple downloads were active I was looking for a solution to attach all downloads when the app restarts without waiting for each AttachAsync. My hope was that the downloads would then run in parallel just as they do if started multiple times using StartAsync (when the method that invokes StartAsync is executed multiple times). But that does not happen. With AtttachAsync only one download runs at a time.

Comment: @Jürgen Bayer - Ok, I think I see what you are saying. I apologize for being slow. Your issue is NOT that that your code is being serialized. It in fact runs in parallel. Your issue IS that the background downloader is serializing the downloads after a restart. Is that correct? Just to take it one step further - why is it important to have the downloads run in parallel? Is it a speed issue? That your downloads now take longer to complete? Any other reason?

Comment: @Jürgen Bayer - After re-reading your first comment above, it looks like what you are after, maybe, is knowing when each download finishes? If this is the case, the `while` loop in my code above acts as the completion handler.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is not too late but I know exactly what you are talking about. I'm also trying to resume all downloads when the application starts.

After hours of trying, here's the solution that works.

**The trick is to let the download operation resume first before attacking the progress handler.**

```
downloadOperation.Resume();
await downloadOperation.AttachAsync().AsTask(cts.Token);
```